# PHP multiple search query returns all rows

Tags: php, mysql

The problem is that i'm trying to get specific search result but it, gives all database rows, not the filtered result. how can i avoid this?

```
require_once 'db/connect.php';

if(isset($_GET['submit'])){
    $doctor = $db->escape_string($_GET['doctor']);
    $specialization = $db->escape_string($_GET['specialization']);
    $hospital = $db->escape_string($_GET['hospital']);

    $query = $db->query("
         SELECT docname, specialization,hospital
         From doctor
         WHere docname Like '%{$doctor}%' or
         specialization like '%{$specialization}%' or
         hospital like '%{$hospital}%'
        ");
?>




<div class="result-count">
    Found <?php echo $query->num_rows; ?> results.
</div>

<?php

if($query -> num_rows){
    while($r = $query->fetch_object()){
        ?>
          <div class="result-count">
             <a href="#"><?php  echo $r->docname; ?></a>
          </div>
        <?php
    }
}
}
```

Comment: sidenote: given what you posted and if it's your real code, you should be getting a parse error with the way you braced the conditional statement.

Comment: if any one condition match then display this result

Comment: @Fred-ii- i didn't got any errors, but it gives all the database results

Comment: you sure about that? http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php

Comment: You can avoid it by writing an SQL query that is giving you the desired result.

Comment: @YourCommonSense is there better sql  query than this?

Comment: Yes, of course. One that works.

Comment: I suspect the easiest way to fix this would be to use `and` rather than `or` between your predicates.

Answer (score 1):

You have to remove unused fields from WHERE clause. Otherwise the `hospital like '%%'` condition will effectively match every row in the table.

So in your case you should create the query on the fly, adding conditions for non-empty fields only.

And **of course** it just enormously helps *to print the resulting query out.* It will not only give you an idea, what SQL you are running, but also *make your question sensible.*

Comment: how can i do that ?

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
require_once 'db/connect.php';

if(isset($_GET['submit'])){
   $doctor = $db->escape_string($_GET['doctor']);
   $specialization = $db->escape_string($_GET['specialization']);
   $hospital = $db->escape_string($_GET['hospital']);
   $where = array();
   if (!empty($doctor)) {
        array_push($where, "docname like '%{$doctor}%'");
   }
   if (!empty($specialization)) {
        array_push($where, "specialization like '%{$specialization}%'");
   }
   if (!empty($hospital)) {
        array_push($where, "hospital like '%{$hospital}%'");
   }
$sql = "SELECT docname, specialization, hospital "
       . "FROM doctor";
if (!empty($where)) {
    $sql .= "WHERE " . implode(' OR ', $where);
}
$query = $db->query($sql);

?>
```